# MySQL connection error : ORA-28500: connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system

Tags: mysql, oracle-11g-r2, mysql-8.0, odbc

Most of the time we don't have issues with the connection from Oracle (using DB link and ODBC driver) to the mySQL DB. However, every once in a while we get the error which persistes for like 30 min:

java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28500: connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system returned this message:
[MySQL][ODBC 8.0(a) Driver] {HY000,NativeErr = 517}

ORA-28500: connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system returned this message:
[MySQL][ODBC 8.0(a) Driver][mysqld-8.0.33-commercial] {HY000}

It's hard to know the root casue since it's not consistent. Any idea?